# Metaplex candy machine rust program redeploy

Tags: anchor, solana-program, metaplex, candy-machine-v2, redeploy

I extract the lib.rs file from the Metaplex candy machine folder. Created a new anchor project via `anchor init`, pasted the smart contract then I run `anchor keys list` and pasted the key in `declare_id` in lib.rs and updated the key in `Anchor.toml` as well. I build and deployed Solana Program successfully on devnet. Now form the front end side it gives me an error
`Error: Account does not exist 6iTW2keSEsGDEV7r1TGFTSYHKJKW5HKWZa1oR8Yg5yCX`

The Project works fine with the previous Solana Program. I just redeployed the rust program using my wallet keys and replaced the idl.json file.

```
export const _getState = async (provider, wallet) => {
    const programID = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);
    const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);
    const _program = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [Buffer.from(utils.bytes.utf8.encode('teacher_minting'))],
    program.programId
    );
    console.log(_program.toString());
    const [stakingPubkey] = _program;
    const [userstakingPubkey] =
        await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [wallet.publicKey.toBuffer()],
        program.programId
        );

        console.log("=====================", stakingPubkey.toBase58());
        
    const testdata = await program.account.mintingAccount.fetch(stakingPubkey);
    
    let userdata = [];
    try {
        userdata = await program.account.userMintingAccount.fetch(userstakingPubkey);
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("ud:", userdata, testdata);
}
```

Deployed Program: https://explorer.solana.com/address/CcSFrh2CQdKRCtpJp6mnFZem67GdLU8jJ1MfwEVoLDRm?cluster=devnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to initialize the smart contact after deploying with new address via CLI, that's why it gave me error `Account does not exist`. Here is the code that I run form frontend side very first after deploying to fix the issue:

```
export const initialize = async (provider, wallet) => {
    const programID = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);
    const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);

    await program.rpc.initialize(
        stakingBump,
        wallet.publicKey,
        new anchor.BN(9999),
        new anchor.BN(20),
        new anchor.BN(20),
        new anchor.BN(20),
        new anchor.BN(15e8),
        new anchor.BN(2e9),
        new anchor.BN(2e9),
        new anchor.BN(0),
        1,
        {
         accounts: {
         mintingAccount: stakingPubkey,
         initializer: wallet.publicKey,
         systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
         tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
         rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        },
    });    
}
```

Note: Your initialize function may or may not contain params as it depends on your code implementation. Initialize part will create the missing accounts.